# Is there a 'diff tool' for audio?

Tags: audio, editing

Ideally in Premiere Pro, I'd like to have a way of seeing the changes I make to an audio file that I edit in Audition to be reflected in a workable format for the video editing in Premiere Pro.

I've got an audio-video recording of an on-screen tutorial.  The audio is repeated several times as the speaker repeats herself, and so I generally edit the audio to take the best portions I can to make a nice, whole picture.  The problem is, when I go back into Premiere, it can often be difficult to remember what changes I made to a 10-15+ recording and where everything is supposed to be.  An unfamiliarity with the tutorial'd software doesn't help.

I'd like to be able to see the changes I make visually so I can keep track of what corrections I make.  I almost *never* master the original audio, but I rather cut out certain portions, silence hiss, and insert silence where necessary --- much like the insertions and deletions of a codebase.  (If you're unfamiliar with what I'm talking about, there are countless examples of diffing available just by viewing the edit history of any post on the SE network.)

Is there any such tool for audio?

Comment: Dupes from other stackexchange sites: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/audio-diff-tool/3622 http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2393/program-to-merge-two-mp3s

Answer (score 4):

There is no such tool that I'm aware of and I'm not even sure what exactly the output of such a tool would look like.  What is available, however, is the ability to use the integration between Adobe applications to work on the audio track in Premiere directly in Audition so that you shouldn't have to manage it yourself like this.

In fact, I believe it may even be possible to open a Premiere project right in Audition so that you can see the video as you are making your adjustments.  I think this should make your need for a diff tool unnecessary.

Comment: It took quite a bit of googling, but here is a decent link describing how this is done: http://www.video2brain.com/en/lessons/sending-material-from-premiere-pro-to-audition.

Comment: @Vermiculus - glad you found something.  I would have posted details for you tonight (I don't currently have my A/V system with me.), but glad you found something quicker.  Is it working for you now?

Comment: Previously known as vermiculus checking in. (Don't know how my accounts aren't linked; that's weird.) I have to be honest and say I don't remember if this worked, but my gut feeling is that it didn't. Regardless, thanks for the answer, but I'm holding off on accepting it until a diff tool is pointed to (even though the workflow you suggest was/is certainly a great suggestion!).